# Google Sheets: How can I count the number of times a certain word appears across multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

For example, I have 3 sheets (1 Monday, 2 Wednesday, 3 Friday) and want to count how many times the word "okay" appears in all three. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

How about using countif for each of the sheets, then sum them all?

```
=countif(Monday!1:1000,"okay")+countif(Wednesday!1:1000,"okay")+countif(Friday!1:1000,"okay")
```

Comment: Actually looks like I ran into a problem. It only counts "okay" if "okay" is alone in a cell. If "okay" is in a cell with another word, it doesn't count it. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can use wildcards with countif e.g. countif(Monday!1:1000,"\*okay\*")

Comment: Thanks Tom! Now running into another issue lol. If the word okay is in a single cell multiple times, it only counts that as one. How can I make it so it counts every okay individually?